# React-Native: Passing functions in props.navigation.navigate("XYZScreen", myFunction())

Tags: react-native

in my react-native application, there are two screens. I want to navigate from one screen to another such that if I press a button in the next screen, the first screen should be refreshed using a method doRefreshing() in the first screen.
Example:

```
const FirstScreen = (props) => {
   const doRefreshing = () => {
     ...
   };
   return (
     <View>
       <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate("secondScreen",doRefreshing())}
        >
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
  );
}
```

The example code of second screen:

```
 const SecondScreen = (props) => {
           const doRefreshingInFirstScreen = () => {
             /** What should I do here? */
           };
           return (
             <View>
               <Button
                   onPress={()=>doRefreshingInFirstScreen()}
                >
               </Button>
             </View>
          );
        }
```

Can someone please tell me how shall I refresh the first screen when the button in second screen is pressed and call goes to doRefreshingInFirstScreen()? Or what else I can do to refresh the first screen upon clicking the button in the second screen? Will be really grateful for this help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@maltoze/76773c)

```js
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', {onRefresh: () => console.log('refreshing...')})}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen(props) {
  const { route } = props;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={route.params.onRefresh} title="Refresh" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native re-renders the screen whenever there is state change but this re-rendering will not happen if the screen is not being displayed. As for your scenario, I will suggest using redux to store the values that need to be refreshed from the second screen. Now whenever you go back to the first screen, then if you are reading value from the redux store, it will read the new values for all the variables that needed to be refreshed from the second screen, thus you will have the new values instead of the old ones.